# Redirecting legacy URLs in DotNetNuke

Tags: url, redirect, admin, dotnetnuke

We are building a revamped version of our old site in DotNetNuke.  There are many pages that link to pages on our old site and we would like those old URLs to still lead to relevant information on the new site.  The old URLs end in a variety of extensions, and sometimes in no extension (our old site is a mishmash of several platforms as well as static files).  Does a DNN plugin exist that allows for such redirects?  Friendly URLs aren't entirely adequate.

note: I realize that this could be handled in IIS, but we would like our non-coder, non-admin site manager to be able to handle this dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want to use a Module like this

http://www.dnnsoftware.com/forge/open-url-rewriter-for-dnn-dotnetnuke/view/extensiondetail/project/openurlrewriter

There is another option though. You can actually put URL records into the database directly, I believe you would simply add a record to the TabUrls table, the TABID is the page in DNN you want to point to. Then you put in the URL, and the HTTPStatus of 301.

You could do that for all the old pages if you know where they need to be mapped to in DNN.

Comment: The specific issue we have is that some of our old URLs end in ".html" and some do not.  The solutions we have examined still result in 404 errors on URLs that end in file extensions.

Comment: @Chris is there any related documentation/tutorial about `TabUrls` table? in my prev projects I could redirect old urls like `/PageName/Id/10` to `/PageName/10`, but could not do the same with `/PageName?id=10` (_obviously I don't want to use any module or write any code for redirect_)

Answer (score 0):

You have to force all request through the ASP.NET pipeline, and you can do that by adding only this single line to the web.config of your application:

```
<system.webServer> 

 <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />

</system.webServer>
```